# How do I get the enumeration comma (、) in Google input tools?

Tags: characters, input-methods

I'm using the 漢語拼音 input metod in Google input tools. **How do I get the enumeration comma (、)?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can try the backslash "\".

Comment: I have tried it using the online version. It works.

Comment: Fantastic, also works on Ubuntu 21.04 pinyin input.